# Referencing css class in React component when it has -

Tags: reactjs

hi if I have a css class imported into my React component as below:

```
import classes from './stylesheet.css'
```

How can I reference it, if the class has - in it?

```
<div className={classes.Content}></div>
```

Like for example if the class name is Content-LI if it is, how can I reference it? I mean reference it using classes in the above, it threw me error when I tried to reference it using

```
<div className={classes.Content-LI}></div>
```

It says undefined LI, any help please? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try `<div className={classes["Content-LI"]}></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use modular css structure, First you need to configure css module in `webpack`.
Find the `module` block from `webpack config` and add this line:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader'
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```

Then you can import `css` to your `component` like this:

`import styles from './app.css';`

`<div className={styles.app}>
   <p>This text will be blue</p>
 </div>`

I have found [this](https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/) for more information. Hope its help for you :)

Comment: No my question is, if I have - in the class name for example I want to use like the below    <div className={styles.Content-LI styles.Test-T1}></div>, its giving me error at Li and T1 as undefined.